# SSIS FTP Task Retry when FTP server is not available

Tags: ssis, ftp

I have a simple SSIS package that pulls data from a database and creates a file.  This file then is FTP'd to another server.  I ran into a problem where the FTP server was not available and the package failed without ever sending the file.  I would like to be able to have the package continue to attempt the connection until the server comes back up and the FTP can be successful.

Does anyone have an ideas as to how I could make this occur?

Comment: If this is the only thing that your package does, you can set the retry count higher in the sql server job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the FTP Connection Manager, not the FTP Task itself, you can set the number of Connection Retries.